# Change hight of the header of an NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, header, nstableview

I am trying to change the height of the header of an NSTableVew but after 2 hours, I am still not seeing how to achieve this.

To you know how can it be done?

Thanks and regards,

Comment: What have you tried? Have you done anything with the table's [NSTableHeaderView](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableHeaderView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)?

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass NSTableView like this :

```
@interface myTableView ( )

@property( strong, nonatomic ) NSTableHeaderView * tableHeaderView;

@end

@implementation myTableView

- ( void )awakeFromNib
{
    [ super awakeFromNib ];

    // For example
    CGFloat headerHeight = 50;

    self.tableHeaderView = [ [ NSTableHeaderView alloc ] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect( 0, 0, self.width, headerHeight ) ];

   [ self setHeaderView:self.tableHeaderView ];
```

And voilà!